# Apache rewrite exclude

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

How do I exclude "404.php" from matching this rewrite rule?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?.*$ /news.php?sid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404\.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?.*$ /news.php?sid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just catch it with a previous rule that has the last flag set:

RewriteRule ^(404.php)$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?.*$ /news.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404\.php$ 
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?.*$ /news.php?sid=$1
```

RewriteCond is used to match request URIs for which the following rule should be applied to.

You can learn more here about the header variables that can be used in RewriteCond statements:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond